# SQL-like computation on Dataset: Aggregate function

Tags: dataset, sql

Assume that I have this dataset

```
a = Dataset[{<|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 3|>}]
```

How can I get the total of Key["B"] like this:

[image]

In general, I want to do something like this (here, with sum. but could be anything)

```
SELECT key, sum(value) FROM tbl GROUP BY key
```

Comment: a[Total, "B"]    (* 5 *)

Comment: How can we group a key within a range of values? Let's say I have loads of values for "B" between 0 and 100 and I want to group B in 10 classes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that an operation equivalent to SQL GROUP BY is surprisingly awkward to express:

```
a[GroupBy[Key["A"]] /* Values, <| "A" -> First /* "A", "B" -> Query[Total, "B"] |>]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

If the application will tolerate a resulting dataset that is non-rectangular in shape, then the result can be obtained with a more natural query (more natural for *Mathematica* that is):

```
a[GroupBy@Key@"A", Total, {"B"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

---

**Discussion**

For purposes of discussion, let's consider a more elaborate input dataset:

```
$data = Dataset @
  { <| "A" -> "A1", "B" -> 1, "C" -> -1 |>
  , <| "A" -> "A1", "B" -> 10, "C" -> -10 |>
  , <| "A" -> "A2", "B" -> 2, "C" -> -2 |>
  , <| "A" -> "A2", "B" -> 20, "C" -> -20 |>
  , <| "A" -> "A2", "B" -> 200, "C" -> -200 |>
  , <| "A" -> "A3", "B" -> 3, "C" -> -3 |>
  }
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

We are going to work up to a query that groups by column *A* and gives us the sums of columns *B* and *C*.  We start by grouping on *A*:

```
$data[
  GroupBy[Key["A"]]
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

As we can see, the `GroupBy` operator returns a list of associations each with a single key that names the group value.  This key is redundant as each group also contains the corresponding *A* value.  We will discard the redundant keys using `Values`:

```
$data[
  GroupBy[Key["A"]] /* Values
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

We end up with a list of lists, each sublist containing the associations that comprise a group.  We want to end up with one association for each group, identified by its *A* value.  Since every association within a group has the same value for *A*, we only need to access one of them (here, the first):

```
$data[
  GroupBy[Key["A"]] /* Values
, <| "A" -> First /* "A" |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

We also want each result association to have the sum of the *B* values from the group:

```
$data[
  GroupBy[Key["A"]] /* Values
, <| "A" -> First /* "A"
   , "B" -> Query[Total, "B"]
  |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

We could have written `"B" -> Total /* "B"` instead to get the same result.  But this seemingly innocent form hides a potential performance problem.  It totals *all* columns first, and only afterwards extracts the total for *B*.  In general, this causes quadratic time complexity which could make the query unacceptably slow for large numbers of columns.  The use of `Query[Total, "B"]` avoids this pitfall.  The difference can be seen using `` Dataset`ShowPlan ``:

```
Dataset`ShowPlan[Total /* "B"]
(* Total /* GeneralUtilities`Slice["B"] *)

Dataset`ShowPlan[Query[Total, "B"]]
(* Map[GeneralUtilities`Slice["B"]] /* Total *)
```

For good measure, we wind up by including the sums of the *C* values as well:

```
$data[
  GroupBy[Key["A"]] /* Values
, <| "A" -> First /* "A"
   , "B" -> Query[Total, "B"]
   , "C" -> Query[Total, "C"]
  |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This is our final result.

**Simpler Alternative**

If we are willing to bend a little bit on the shape of the final dataset, we can get the desired data using a much simpler query:

```
$data[GroupBy@Key@"A", Total, {"B", "C"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This dataset is no longer "rectangular" like an SQL table but is rather a nested set of associations.  If the application can tolerate this different shape, then the reduced conceptual complexity of the query is desirable.

**Update: GroupBy@Key?**

An astute commentator points out that, according to the documentation, the last query can leave out the explicit call to `Key`:

```
$data[GroupBy["A"], Total, {"B", "C"}]
```

The same is true for every such usage throughout the post.  Unfortunately, a bug in version 10.0.1 prevented this abbreviated form from working properly.  Fortunately, the bug is fixed in version 10.0.2.  I've left the explicit use of `Key` in place just to be on the safe side, but if one is using 10.0.2, then be aware that a shorter form exists.

Comment: very minor point that use of Key is redundant in that last example - but probably slightly more readable with it.

Comment: @GordonCoale Well spotted.  Technically you are correct, but a bug in 10.0.1 causes the query to fail unless `Key` is explicitly present.  The bug is fixed in 10.0.2.  I left `Key` in place just in case.  I'll add a note to that effect to the response.

Comment: Excellent topic.
I used your codes but need to do an additionnal query. I have to subgroup by classes.
With taking three colums A, B, C, let's say I have hundreds of values for "B" (between 0 and 100) and I want to also group by B from 0 to 10, from 10 to 20...from 90 to 100 resulting in one line per range.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Porty We can group _B_ into bands using something like `GroupBy[{#A &, 10 Quotient[#B, 10] &}]`.  I'm not sure whether this answers your question -- if not you might consider posting a new question with the details.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent answer given by WReach I would like to show, how we can come up with the rectangular result the OP wants:

```
f = Function[ data,

    data // RightComposition[

        Query[ GroupBy["A"], Total /* KeyDrop["A"] ], (* cf. WReach's answer *)
        Query[ KeyValueMap @ Function[ { key, rowdata }, 
            Association[ "A" -> key, rowdata ]
        ] (* make the data rectangular again *)
    ]

];
```

Then

```
f @ Dataset[{<|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 3|>}]
```

[image: OP data]

```
(* using the more elaborate data given by WReach *)
$data = Dataset@{<|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 1, "C" -> -1|>, <|"A" -> "A1", 
"B" -> 10, "C" -> -10|>, <|"A" -> "A2", "B" -> 2, "C" -> -2|>, <|
"A" -> "A2", "B" -> 20, "C" -> -20|>, <|"A" -> "A2", "B" -> 200, 
"C" -> -200|>, <|"A" -> "A3", "B" -> 3, "C" -> -3|>};

f @ $data
```

[image: WReach data]

A couple of things to note (from my experience):

- using `Query` makes the solution more general as `dataset[ op1, op2,... ]` is limited to `Dataset`
- using `RightComposition` (`/*`) allows for very compact code
- applying Query sequentially makes the solution more readable maybe
- using `Function` with named vars also makes code more readable

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Dataset[{<|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 3|>}];

"B" /. Total@a
```

5

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Dataset[{<|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> "A1", "B" -> 3|>}];

Total[a]["B"]
(* 5 *)
```

Comment: 9 upvotes for " It appears that an operation equivalent to SQL GROUP BY is surprisingly awkward to express: "  and 0 for this elegant answer. What am I missing?

Comment: @niloderoock this "elegant answer" is not generalizable to other aggregate operations, also, output is no longer a dataset

Answer (score -1):

Here some exemple of how to query table lists using SQL Like Operators.
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damcalrom/Published/SQL_Operators.nb

Comment: This leads to a page saying: `Sorry, you do not have permission to access this item.`